# Spring request parameter is missing

Tags: java, c#, .net, spring, rest

I'm trying to register a user by sending the `username`, `password`, `firstName` and `lastName` from the **c# client** to the **java application** using **spring**. In the **java application**, it gets the `username` and `password` but `firstName` and `lastName` get lost.

This is the error I get:

```
[org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'firstName' for method parameter type String is not present]
```

This is the c# method I'm using to send the parameters to the java application:

```
public async Task<User> RegisterUserAsync(string username, string password, string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Registering...");
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage =
                await Client.GetAsync($"http://localhost:8080/user/register?username={username}&password={password}&firstname={firstName}&lastname={lastName}");
            if (responseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                string userAsJson = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                User resultUser = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<User>(userAsJson);
                Console.WriteLine("Registered");
                return resultUser; //EXPECTED A USUAL USER TO BE RETURNED 
            }

            throw new Exception("User could not be registered");
        }
```

When debugging it shows that all parameters have **correct values**, but java does not **receive** them

Java application register method:

```
@GetMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<User> ValidateRegister(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password, @RequestParam String firstName, @RequestParam String lastName)
    {
        try{
            System.out.println(username);
            User user = userService.ValidateRegister(username,password,firstName,lastName);

            if(user == null) {
                return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
            }
            return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }
    }
```

If I put `firstName` and `lastName` as `required = false`, then it registers the user only with `username` and `password`.

The question is why does the `username` and `password` get through but `firstName` and `lastName` doesn't ?

Comment: One suggestion, please use post not get to create resource

Comment: But basically, I need only to get the data to the java and it sends the info to another java server which is the database through sockets. So how would changing it to post help here? Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you do not explicitly specify the name of the parameter, which makes Spring parse the parameters by the name of the variables. And they are different for you: in С# you pass `firstname` and `lastname`, but in java your parameters are called `firstName` and `lastName`

Try it in java-code:

```java
@RequestParam(name = "firstname") String firstName, @RequestParam(name = "lastname") String lastName
```

or (better) fix your C# client:

```
Client.GetAsync($"http://localhost:8080/user/register?username={username}&password={password}&firstName={firstName}&lastName={lastName}");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using camel case for the variable name in your Java code: `firstName` and `lastName`. In the other hand the request parameter name is not using camel case: `&firstname=...` and `&lastname`. In this case I suggest explicitly specifying the name of the parameter in `@RequestParam`:

```
@RequestParam("firstname") String firstName
```

This is not part of your question, but please avoid sending passwords as a request parameter. This will send it as clear text, you may want to send it in the request body. Also,`GET` requests should be used for actions which are not modifying the state of back-end. Please use `POST` or `PUT` modifying actions, like registering users.